# Access 2013: How to Return All Records With Date Older than X?

Tags: sql, date, ms-access-2013

### My Problem

I have a date field in the table in question. I'm trying to create a query that will only display records where that date field are 120 days old or older.

### My Code

*Solution Attempt 1*

The first solution I tried was simply added criteria to my date field. The criteria formula I used was:

```
< Date()-120
```

This removed a few 'random' records leaving me with 714 of my original 905 records. Unfortunately, a quick look through the dates of remaining records in ascending order, it was obvious that I was still getting records more recent that 120 days old.

Based on my 'random' result above, I double checked the format of my field by changing the field to:

```
DATE: Format([myDtField], "mm/dd/yyyy")
```

I ran the query again - this reduced the number of records removed, leaving me with 734 of 905 - but my issue persisted - I still had records with dates more recent than 120 old.

*Solution Attempt 2*

Based on my issues above, I decided to go a different route. This time I created a unique field for my criteria calculation. For the field value I used:

```
DateDiff: DateDiff("d",[myDtField],Date())
```

This resulted in values that were very far off from the correct values (ex. a record with a date of yesterday resulted in 43!).

*Solution Attempt 3*

This was less of a solution and more just troubleshooting, but based on the results I'm getting, I keep thinking my dates aren't being perceived by the system as the date it's displaying (i.e. DateValue() is off compared to displayed value). I spot checked a few of the dates vs their DateValue() and the randomly selected records all seemed to be correct. So again, no luck.

*Solution Attempt 4*
@Gustov reminded me about the DateValue() function. I've attempted that on the field as well - the field is imported as a text field, thus needs converted to a date value. Similar to the formula Gustov posted, for my field value I used:

```
DATEDIFF: DateDiff("d",Nz(DateValue([LASTPAYDT]),0),Date())
```

And then in the criteria I simply used the formula:

```
>120
```

This results in the following error:

> Data type mismatch in criteria expression

This was probably the closest solution I had, simply because WITHOUT criteria it returns the proper values (i.e. a date of yesterday returned "1", while a date of two days ago returned "2"... etc). So you would think simply limiting records where this field is >120 would work, but then it throws up the error above.

### My Question

1. Does anyone have an idea of how to check if a record field is 120
   days old or older?
2. If either of my above solutions works for question 1, then what might be wrong with my date field that is causing issues if I am going about it the right way?
3. @Gustov's DateValue() solution is close (i.e. provides the correct values), but adding criteria causes an error. Any solutions?

I'm at a loss. An extra set of eyes on this problem would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Is the datatype of your `myDtField` text or Date/Time?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hans touches something. If the dates are not dates but text, try this:

```
Select * From YourTable
Where 
    IsDate([myDtField])
    And
    DateDiff("d", DateValue([myDtField]), Date()) > 120
```

Comment: I apologize Gustav, I didn't mention in my question that I've also tried the DateValue() function (I'll update question to reflect that). I feel some type of conversion is necessary (either DateValue() or Format(), as the field is imported as a text field). -- When using DateValue (i.e. your exact statement above) Access errors with `Data type mismatch in criteria expression`. So I'm not sure what the next steps there would be.

Comment: Then you probably have some Null values or unreadable dates. See edit to filter those out.

Comment: That worked! I had to modify slightly for "Design View" I had to make it `DATEDIFF: IIf(IsDate([myDtField]),DateDiff("d",DateValue([myDtField]),Date()),0)` with criteria of `>120` -- I'm used to working in SQL view for Access Queries, but this is an append query with 62 fields, so it got a bit hectic in SQL view ;-)

Comment: Great! Thanks for the feedback.

Answer (score 0):

I have tried this and it works, DATAText is the data stored as a text.

```
SELECT Tabella1.ID, Tabella1.DATAText, Date() AS Espr1
FROM Tabella1
WHERE (cDate(Format(Tabella1.DataText,"yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss")))<Date()-120;
```